# Mininet TCP Congestion Control Losing Its Fairness Upon Reaching 5 Connections?

Tags: python, tcp, mininet, congestion-control

I am using Mininet to experiment around with TCP congestion control. [This is the network that is currently being tested.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Saif8.png) The Python code for this topology is as follows.

```py
class ServerClient(Topo):
    def build(self):
        h1 = self.addHost('h1', cls=Host, defaultRoute=None)
        h2 = self.addHost('h2', cls=Host, defaultRoute=None)
        h3 = self.addHost('h3', cls=Host, defaultRoute=None)
        h4 = self.addHost('h4', cls=Host, defaultRoute=None)
        h5 = self.addHost('h5', cls=Host, defaultRoute=None)
        h6 = self.addHost('h6', cls=Host, defaultRoute=None)
        
        server = self.addHost('server', cls=Host, defaultRoute=None)
        
        s1 = self.addSwitch('s1', cls=OVSKernelSwitch, failMode='standalone')
        s2 = self.addSwitch('s2', cls=OVSKernelSwitch, failMode='standalone')
        
        self.addLink(h1, s1, cls=TCLink, bw=1000, delay='0.2ms')
        self.addLink(h2, s1, cls=TCLink, bw=1000, delay='0.2ms')
        self.addLink(h3, s1, cls=TCLink, bw=1000, delay='0.2ms')
        self.addLink(h4, s1, cls=TCLink, bw=1000, delay='0.2ms')
        self.addLink(h5, s1, cls=TCLink, bw=1000, delay='0.2ms')
        self.addLink(h6, s1, cls=TCLink, bw=1000, delay='0.2ms')
        
        self.addLink(s1, s2, cls=TCLink, bw=500, delay='0.2ms')
        
        self.addLink(server, s2, cls=TCLink, bw=1000, delay='0.2ms')
```

All links in this network have a small delay of 0.2ms and have no packet losses. However, I am seeing weird behaviours when there are 5 or more `iperf3`s running in parallel. My computer has TCP congestion control set to Reno using `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=reno`.

This was run on each host with 20 seconds delay between them.

```
h1: iperf3 -c <Server IP> -P 1 -p 20000 -t 140
h2: iperf3 -c <Server IP> -P 1 -p 20001 -t 120
h3: iperf3 -c <Server IP> -P 1 -p 20002 -t 100
h4: iperf3 -c <Server IP> -P 1 -p 20003 -t 80
h5: iperf3 -c <Server IP> -P 1 -p 20004 -t 60
h6: iperf3 -c <Server IP> -P 1 -p 20005 -t 40
```

This code was used to run them in parallel.

```py
    def run_iperf(hostid):
        with open('./res/h' + str(hostid + 1) + '.txt', 'w') as f:
            port = 20000 + hostid
            server.popen('iperf3 -s -p ' + str(port))
            command = 'iperf3 -c ' + server.IP() + ' -P 1 -p ' + str(port) + ' -t ' + str((6 - hostid) * 20 + 20)
            procs.append([hosts[hostid].popen(command, stdout=f), f])
            time.sleep(20)
    
    for i in range(6):
        run_iperf(i)
```

[This was the result of each host's transfer rate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMVAo.png) You can see that all hosts get a similar level of bandwidth until `h5` joins the testing, where `h3`'s transfer rate surges, and `h5` fails to send much. That is not the case with `h6`, which gains large amount of share, and later dips.

This test was repeated multiple times, and it has shown similar result. The fairness breaks as soon as 5 or more hosts start running `iperf3`. I have tried using `-C reno` just in case, but the result was similar.

I have also conducted similar test where `h6` is the `iperf3` server. The result was as expected this time. [This was the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AIk7.png) All 5 maintained similar level of transfer rate.

I would like to know what exactly is causing the unfairness. Thank you.